# Setting value to a not-existing array item?

Tags: vb.net, exception

Please take a look at the following code:

```
Try
  Dim Reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(PositionsFileName)
  Do While Reader.Peek() <> -1
    Dim Positions() As String = Reader.ReadLine().Split("|")
    If (Positions(0) Is Nothing) Or (Positions(1) Is Nothing) Or (Positions(2) Is Nothing) Then
      ' something
    End If
  Loop
Catch ex As Exception
  ex.Source = Nothing
End Try
```

I am reading a file and expecting format something|something1|something2. I am trying to make it set "Nothing" to the array index which does not exists (the file format is broken), so that the If statement goes smoothly, but it seem I am doing it wrong. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: How many "Somethings" will it read? You can do If Position.lenght() = 0 to know if split was sucessful.

Comment: You should remove your `Catch ex As Exception`. It isn't really helping you to write better code and just hides errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `Split("|")` and there are only 2 items (for example, `something|something1`), `Positions(2)` will not be `Nothing`, it will just not be there. So your code will raise an exception, something about `index out of bounds of the array`.

If you need `Positions(2)` contain `Nothing` in this case, you code can look like this:

```
Dim Positions(2) As String
Dim tmpArray() As String = Reader.ReadLine().Split("|")
For i = 0 To UBound(Positions)
  If i <= UBound(tmpArray) Then
    Positions(i) = tmpArray(i)
  Else
    Positions(i) = Nothing
  End If
Next
```

Comment: That is why I want that exception to be catched and "Nothing" to be set to the Position(2) so the If statement fails. How to set that value? What about the `ex.Source = Nothing` is wrong?

Comment: @barakuda28: `ex.Source = Nothing` will not help you set `Position(2) = Nothing`. See my edit for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you only have three "Somethings" per valid line. If so, try writing your `Positions()` assignment like this:

```
Dim Positions() As String = Reader _
    .ReadLine() _
    .Split("|") _
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Nothing", 3)) _
    .Take(3) _
    .ToArray()
```

This will ensure that you have three items every time. No need to check for nothings.

Answer (score 1):

Just check positions.length after the split. Also, if you want to check for cases like "||Something2|Something3", the first position will be "" not Nothing. The orelse is a shortcircuit that will keep the latter condtitions from being evaulated if an earlier condition is met.

```
If Positions.length < 3 OrElse Positions(0) = "" OrElse Positions(1) = "" OrElse Positions(2) = "" Then
  ' something
End If
```